# passing a function with an arbitrary amount of parameters

Tags: function, haskell, parameters, parameter-passing

I've recently been learning haskell from [this awesome site](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#curried-functions), and I just learned about passing functions as parameters in the *Higher Order Functions* chapter. I can see how passing functions as parameters can be extremely useful, but from my current(lowley) understanding you need to specify the amount of parameters in this function, which can be quite limited given this function:

```
--takes a function and returns a function that has flipped arguments
flip' :: (a -> b -> c) -> (b -> a -> c) --very limited
flip' f = g
    where g x y = f y x
```

useful, but only to the point of functions taking two parameters, is there a way to write a function definition that accepts functions with an arbitrary amount of parameters? My guess would have to be some sort of parameter list, but I can't seem to find any information on it. Thanks!

Comment: To get to the point faster: always remember that _every Haskell function has exactly **one** argument_! Your two-parameter functions are barely curried functions mapping the first argument to another function, and there's no reason this can't continue to arbitrary numbers; `flip` won't care.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually `flip` works with functions with more than two parameters, but might not be exactly what you need:

```
Prelude> :t (,,,)
(,,,) :: a -> b -> c -> d -> (a, b, c, d)
Prelude> :t flip (,,,)
flip (,,,) :: b -> a -> c -> d -> (a, b, c, d)
```

since

```
(,,,) :: a -> b -> c -> d -> (a, b, c, d)
```

is

```
(,,,) :: a -> (b -> (c -> (d -> (a, b, c, d))))
```

the first two parameters get flipped. Here `a` is `a`, `b` is `b`, but `c` is `c -> d -> (a, b, c, d)`.

And then again, what do you expect to achieve by flipping a 3 parameter function like in this example?

EDIT: And also, there are vararg functions - one example is `printf`. [This](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Varargs) Haskell.org page is pretty nice. In short, some typeclass magic could be used to achieve this effect.

Comment: I'm not specifically looking for a solution to allow me to flip, but more on HOW I could create such a function if there is a way.

Comment: @Gmercer015: Edited. `printf` blew my mind at the time I first read about it, so this might not be as straightforward as it seems in other languages, but is definitely elegant and no hack required. I think this does not fit into the part of LYAH you are reading on - it should probably be later, and I don't think it ever gets mentioned in that tutorial.

Comment: @Gmercer015 You already created such a function.  The flip you wrote in your question will work on any function that takes at least two parameters.  Try your `flip'` on a function of three parameters if you don't believe me.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez That's the point, it **only** works for function with two parameters. What if i wanted to pass a 3 parameter function but still wanted flip to handle this?

Comment: @Gmercer015 Is it not just the case in my answer?

Comment: @Gmercer015 No.  Your `flip'` works for functions of three parameters.  Just try it right now if you do not believe me.

Comment: I just had an epiphany, thank you guys for the help! I understand what you're saying now.

Comment: @Gmercer015 Yeah, the trick is realizing that the `c` in the type signature of your `flip'` can itself be a function of even more parameters.